# File is copied then complains it does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code;

```
string oldPath = @"C:\\Users\\akclark.DOMAIN-A\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\WebSites\\Quote\\quote.xlsx";
string newFileName = "" + GlobalVariables.quoteNumber + "_" + GlobalVariables.quoteRevision + ".xlsx";
string newPath = @"C:\\Users\\akclark.DOMAIN-A\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\WebSites\\Quote\\" + newFileName;
FileInfo f1 = new FileInfo(oldPath);
if (f1.Exists)
{
    FileInfo f2 = new FileInfo(newPath);
    if (f2.Exists){
    File.Delete(newPath);
    } else {

        File.Copy(oldPath, newPath);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", f2.Length.ToString());
        Response.TransmitFile(newPath);
        Response.End();

    }
}

else
{
    Label20.Visible = true;
    Label20.Text = "Excel Template not found! Please Contact IT Department with this message.";
}
```

Everytime I run the code, it complains at `Response.TransmitFile(newPath);` that the file is not found.

I am running Windows 7 Pro, x64 With Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. This is .NET 4.5 Web Project.

But I just copied it three lines earlier. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you added a breakpoint so that you can check if the file was actually copied?

Comment: When you use string literals (the @ sign in front of a string) you don't need to double backslash the path. Either do `@"C:\mydocument.txt"` or `C:\\mydocument.txt`. Don't do both at the same time.

Comment: @CryptoJones, `the file is not found` - could you please post error + stack trace please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
@"C:\\Users\\akclark.DOMAIN-A\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\WebSites\\Quote\\"
```

Verbatim string + double backslashes = file path with double backslashes, which could be treated by `FileInfo` and `Response.TransmitFile` differently.

Comment: Both `File.Exists(@"C:\temp\file.txt")` and `File.Exists(@"C:\\temp\\file.txt")` return `true` (assuming the file.txt file is in the C:\Temp folder). I tried this in LinqPad. I agree that backlashes in literal strings shouldn't be escaped.

Comment: @MarioJVargas, what about this one `Response.TransmitFile(newPath)`?

Comment: @aleksey.berezan , yes, to my amazement it also works. Just tried it using the above example I described. I wasn't trying to disprove your answer, just adding that the System.IO.File and System.IO.FileInfo classes don't seem to care. It must be an OS behavior rather than the .NET Framework itself. My first instinct was to also mention that the use of literal strings was the problem, but after trying it I refrained from answering.

Comment: I am running Windows 7 Pro x64 if that helps you guys understand it better?

Comment: hm ... I tried the sample on win-8+.net 4.5.1+asp.net 4.0.30319+iis express and didn't have any issue mentioned in topic.

Comment: @CryptoJones, what's you stack?

Comment: @aleksey.berezan Taking the '@' out of my string fixed the problem. Do you still want to see the stack?

Comment: @CryptoJones, yeah, stack would be helpful for the guys having same problem in the future. Better to add it to topic tags, I think.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan Do you want me to add the '@' back into the strings and then take the stack?

Comment: @CryptoJones, no, I meant not stack trace but technology stack: versions of your OS/.net framework/asp.net/IIS. Sorry for all this mess

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below line

```
if (f2.Exists)
            {
                File.Delete(newPath);
            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(oldPath, newPath);
                f2 = new FileInfo(newPath);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AddHeader("content-length", f2.Length.ToString());
                Response.TransmitFile(newPath);
                Response.End();

            }
```

you code have  Response.AddHeader("content-length", f2.Length.ToString()); and f2 is initialize before copy so it is unable to find and throw the error file not found.